# transform SQL adjacency list to R adjacency matrix

Tags: r, data-structures, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

I have a MySQL table `pedigree` that stores all my interconnecting parentage data as 2 adjacency lists:

### Pedigree table

```
org_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
dam_id INT UNSIGNED,
sire_id INT UNSIGNED,
FOREIGN KEY (org_id) REFERENCES organisms(org_id)
FOREIGN KEY (dam_id) REFERENCES organisms(org_id),
FOREIGN KEY (sire_id) REFERENCES organisms(org_id)
```

- Any `org_id` may or may not have children. Number of children is unlimited.
- Each `org_id` in the `pedigree` table is required to have at least a dam_id OR a sire_id
- If an `org_id` has no parents, it will not be listed in the pedigree table except as a sire or dam
- An `org_id` may have `dam_id==sire_id`

### Sample Data

```
Org Dam Sire
23, 42, 57
26, 25, 25
27, 43, 43
28, 44, 44
30, 25, 25
31, 45, 25
32, 45, 45
33, 31, 32
34, 28, 59
35, 27, 28
36, 28, 28
39, 38, 34
41, 27, 24
```

I want to use R's `igraph` package (unless there is something more appropriate) to display a directed DAG of my pedigrees with ancestor nodes occurring above child nodes. I am unclear about exactly what igraph needs to do this.  I think I need to generate an adjacency  matrix from my adjacency list, but I'm at a loss as to how to do this efficiently.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using an edge list. Two column matrix with each edge as a row in the matrix. igraph will pull the names for the nodes from the values in the edge list as well.

```
g <- graph.edgelist(el)
```

And if you need the adjacency matrix for some reason

```
adj.mat <- get.adjacency(g)
```